# C - Unreferenced Omp function

Tags: c, openmp

I'm working on 'C' parallel programming for my studies using Omp. In my module **array-sum-parallel.c** I include as first, as requested, the file *hpc.h* that is in the same folder of my C file and contains the following code:

```
/*This header file provides a function double hpc_gettime() that returns the elaps  
ed time (in seconds) since "the epoch". The function uses the timing routing of th  
e underlying parallel framework (OpenMP or MPI), if enabled; otherwise, the defaul  
t is to use the clock_gettime() function.

IMPORTANT NOTE: to work reliably this header file must be the FIRST header file th  
at appears in your code.*/

#ifndef HPC_H  
#define HPC_H  
#if defined(_OPENMP)  
#include <omp.h>  
/* OpenMP timing routines */

double hpc_gettime( void )
{
    return omp_get_wtime();
}

#elif defined(MPI_Init)  
/* MPI timing routines */  
double hpc_gettime( void )
{
    return MPI_Wtime();
}

#else  
/* POSIX-based timing routines */  
#if _XOPEN_SOURCE < 600  
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600  
#endif  
#include <time.h>  

double hpc_gettime( void )
{
    struct timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts );
    return ts.tv_sec + (double)ts.tv_nsec / 1e9;
}  
#endif  
#endif
```

Then I include *omp.h, stdio.h, stdlib.h*, I compile with *gcc -c -Wall -Wpedantic -fopenmp* and it's ok, but when I link with `gcc -o -fopenmp array-sum-parallel array-sum-parallel.o` I get this error:
**array-sum-parallel.c:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to omp_set_num_threads** and all the others Omp functions. Why?

Comment: The `-c` flag to `gcc` only does the compile stage, the output file isn't linked yet. Easiest solution if you want to compile and link in one step is leave out `-c`

Comment: I am 100% sure you cannot *execute* the file you get from `gcc -c -Wall -Wpedantic -fopenmp` on any platform. Do you mean when you try to link it?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Yes, I mean the linking sorry. I edited the question.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Now it works thanks. I needed to link with _-fopenmp_ during the linking phase, and not when I compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to link your compiled files with omp library, you can use g++ to compile and link with single command :

```
g++ -o sum-parallel sum-parallel.c -fopenmp
```

Comment: I edited the question because problem was in the linking phase and not about the executable obviously. Your code works, just like works with `gcc -o array-sum array-sum-parallel.o fopenmp` after `the gcc -c...` . Why _fopenmp_ need to be the last flag?

Comment: It could be first flag, no restriction

Comment: But this way `gcc -o -fopenmp array-sum array-sum-parallel.o'` tells me that file `array-sum` doesn't exist.  
This way `gcc -o array-sum array-sum-parallel.o -fopenmp` it's ok.

Comment: lookat gcc command structure, -o <outputfile> , -o requires output file name right after it and in your case you're telling gcc to output into a file named -fopenmp, any file names right after that would be compiled and linked, the gcc compiler do find for file named array-sum which isn't exits,  put -fopenmp before -o solves the problem